# Strange behavior with pack('L')

Tags: ruby, io, pack

If I try to write a packed byte as an unsigned int32 to a file, using `pack('L')`, the number `10` writes as five bytes. With any another number I get the normal behavior.

I wrote simple script:

```
x = 0
while x < 100 do
    puts "\nTesting %s..." % [x]
    h = [x].pack('L')
    puts "h length: %s" % [h.length]
    f = File.open('tmp', 'w')
    f.write h
    puts "position: %s" % [f.pos]
    x += 1
end
```

and get [this result](http://pastebin.com/AiL0Qyfm); Look at iteration number 10.

Where is my mistake?

Ruby version: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: Running your snippet on `ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin12.1.0]` I get `4` bytes all the way down :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a newline translation issue (Windows-specific): byte 10 is translated to CR+LF.

I don't know ruby, but `open` with `wb` instead of `w` might help.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally clicked.